# Python server is sending truncated images over TCP

Tags: python, tcp, server

I have a simple server on my Windows PC written in python that reads files from a directory and then sends the file to the client via TCP.

Files like HTML and Javascript are received by the client correctly (sent and original file match).
The issue is that **image data is truncated**.

Oddly, different images are truncated at different lengths, but it's consistent per image.
For example, a specific 1MB JPG is always received as 95 bytes. Another image which should be 7KB, is received as 120 bytes.

Opening the truncated image files in notepad++, the data that *is* there is correct. (The only issue is that the file ends too soon).
I do not see a pattern for where the files end. The chars/bytes immediately before and after truncation are different per image.

I've tried three different ways for the server to read the files, but they all have the same result.

Here is a snippet of the reading and sending of files:

```
print ("Cache size=" + str(os.stat(filename).st_size))

#1st attempt, using readlines
fileobj = open(filename, "r") 
cacheBuffer = fileobj.readlines() 
for i in range(0, len(cacheBuffer)):
    tcpCliSock.send(cacheBuffer[i])
```

```
#2nd attempt, using line, same result
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        tcpCliSock.send(f)
```

```
#3rd attempt, using f.read(), same result
with open(filename) as f:
    tcpCliSock.send(f.read())
```

The script prints to the console the size of the file read, and *the number of bytes matches the original image*. So this proves the problem is in sending, right?
If the issue is with sending, what can I change to have the whole image sent properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dealing with images, which are binary files, you need to open the files in *binary* mode.

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```

From the Python documentation for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability. (Appending `'b'` is useful even on systems that don’t treat binary and text files differently, where it serves as documentation.)

Since your server is running on Windows, as you `read` the file, Python is converting every `\r\n` it sees to `\n`. For text files, this is nice: You can write platform-independent code that only deals with `\n` characters.  For binary files, this *completely corrupts your data*. That's why it's important to use `'b'` when dealing with binary files, but also important to leave it off when dealing with text files.

---

Also, as TCP is a stream protocol, it's better to *stream* the data into the socket in smaller pieces. This avoids the need to read an entire file into memory, which will keep your memory usage down. Like this:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(4096)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        tcpCliSock.send(data)
```

Comment: Is there a reason NOT to ALWAYS use binary mode? Will that create a issue for any text?